# How to delete only a specific version of a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, revision-history

I want to delete a specific version of a question, but deleting the question itself is not an option. Do you provide any such functionality?

Comment: You can make any particular version the current version, which is what people will see if that's what you mean. That's mainly used to revert bad edits.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We do, but you'll need to [contact us directly](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). Let us know:

- The link to the question itself
- In what revision something was posted that shouldn't have been
- What that something is so we can look for it
- That you're certain the *current* version of the question is acceptable

We may, depending on which revision it is, have to delete all *but* the current revision, because diffs kinda break when you take chunks out of the middle. But, the first step is to contact us.

This is (for now) a *hard* delete, so it's only available to employees. We hope to make this 'soft' so that we can extend the functionality to moderators, but that's proven to be a bit more difficult than anticipated.